# Why is my Form on top when I hover over a GMap.NET control?

Tags: c#, winforms, gmap.net

I have a GMap.NET control on my main form, and then I have a second form that will show when the user clicks on a button. The problem is, that when the user leaves the second window and hovers over the GMap control from the main form, the main form comes to the front. This does not happen when i hover over the rest of the main window with the second window on the front. Also I have another form that will show while the program searches for some data, and this one will also disappear when the user hovers over the map.

I hope I explained it well enough, basically when I hover over the map the main window comes to the front. And it does only happen when there is another form of my project in front of it, not when there is any other window like firefox or something in the front.

So my question is: why does this happen and can I change this behavior? Is it a standard of the GMap.NET control? I am using the Version 1.7.0.0 control btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to see some code as to how you are showing the forms, but it sounds like you are doing something like secondwindow.Show() instead of secondwindow.ShowDialog(), and then an event from GMap for OnEnter is doing a Focus().

Then, when you have the "other form" in front of it, it's opened in a way that will restrict access to the parent form (ShowDialog(), etc).

Comment: The showDialog() works in my case, but there is no code from me at least to do a focus() for OnEnter... But since this works thank you very much!

Answer (score 12):

you must use

```
GMap1.DisableFocusOnMouseEnter = true;
```

i added this code to my program and problem solved.